# Vector2List not working as expected : Dart // Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, vectormath

I'm working on a game and using Vector2List to represent the positions of many particles.
Let's say I want to increase the X value by 4.

When I use a single Vector2 I can do something like this and everything goes fine:

```
position.x += 4;
```

*Where position is an instance of Vector2*

If Vector2 was {3, 5} then it becomes {7, 5} (everything is OK).

But if I'm using a vector list, I would do something like:

```
position[i].x += 4
```

*Where i is the particle index and position is an instance of Vector2List*

Then it goes from {3, 5} to {3, 5} (no change at all!).

The only way I found to get this done was using the function set values, but it doesn't look like it should be mandatory. Am I doing something wrong?

**What is NOT working**

```
position[i].x += 4;
```

**What is working**

```
position.setValues(i, position[i].x+4, position[i].y);
```

**Sample code**

```
          Vector2List positions = Vector2List(1);
          print('positions[0] = ${positions[0]}');
          positions[0].x += 4;
          positions[0].y += 10;
          print('positions[0] after operation = ${positions[0]}');
          positions.setValues(0, positions[0].x + 4, positions[0].y + 10);
          print('positions[0] after setValues = ${positions[0]}');
```

**The result is**

```
I/flutter (32638): positions[0] = [0.0,0.0]
I/flutter (32638): positions[0] after operation = [0.0,0.0]
I/flutter (32638): positions[0] after setValues = [4.0,10.0]
```

**My software**

Flutter version Channel Stable 2.0.1
Dart SDK version: 2.12.0 (stable)
I'm using null safety.

Please forgive any English mistake, I'm not a native speaker.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how the `[]` operator is implemented for [`Vector2List`](https://pub.dev/documentation/vector_math/latest/vector_math_lists/VectorList/operator_get.html):

```
T operator [](int index) {
  final r = newVector();
  load(index, r);
  return r;
}
```

As you can see, it will actually create a new vector object and return this after it is filled with data. This means any modifications to this new vector object does not result in any change in the `Vector2List` object.

What you can do is something like this:

```
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_lists.dart';

void main() {
  Vector2List positions = Vector2List(1);
  print('positions[0] = ${positions[0]}');

  positions[0] = positions[0]
    ..x += 4
    ..y += 10;

  print('positions[0] after operation = ${positions[0]}');
  // positions[0] after operation = [4.0,10.0]
}
```

It is still not great, but does the same that you do but more simplified. The most optimal way I think is to create a new `Vector2`and use it with the `+=` operator on `Vector2List`:

```
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_lists.dart';

void main() {
  Vector2List positions = Vector2List(2);
  print('positions[0] = ${positions[0]}');

  positions[0] += Vector2(4, 10);

  print('positions[0] after operation = ${positions[0]}');
  // positions[0] after operation = [4.0,10.0]
}
```

Comment: I see... Since the vscode tip said the x was a setter and after all I'm dealing with a list of vectors I thought it should work since it works with individual vectors. Is very weird to edit a Vector and it doesn't change anything at all.

Thank you.

Comment: By the way, do you know if creating a Vector2 and summing it is more expensive than using "setvalues(index, x, y)"? I'm not a very experiented programmer and the only way I can think to test is run the whole simulation with both implementations and see which one goes faster.

Comment: @Renan It should be more or less the same for both of my examples since the `[]` operator will create a new `Vector2` object. You should really pick the one you think makes your code most readable. You could say my solutions are a little better compared to your own since you are calling `positions[0]` two times (for reading x and y) where you then creates two `Vector2` objects (you could then just cache the value of `positions[0]`. But since all these objects are very short lived, they should really not affect the performance in most situations.

Comment: But you could save `Vector2(4, 10)` into a static (or class member) variable if you are going to use this vector a lot and then prevent creating this value for every time you want to add it to another vector.